# Stationary points of a cubic function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, cubics, stationary-point

If t is a positive constant, find the local maximum and minimum values of the function

$f(x) = (3x^2 - 4)\left(x - t + \frac{1}{t}\right)$

and show that the difference between them is $\frac{4}{9}(t + 1/t)^3$.

Find the least value of this difference as $t$ is varied.

**My attempt:**

\begin{align*}
f(x) & = (3x^2 - 4)\left(x - t + \frac{1}{t}\right)\\
f'(x) & = (3x^2 - 4)(1) + 6x\left(x - t + \frac{1}{t}\right)\\
\end{align*}
Stationary points when $f'(x) = 0$.
$$0 = 9x^2 - 6x\left(t - \frac{1}{t}\right) - 4$$
Find values for $x$ using quadratic formula gives
$$x = \frac{\left(t - \frac{1}{t}\right) \pm \sqrt{t^2 + \frac{1}{t^2}}}{3}$$
I am not sure if this is right so far, but if it is ... it seems very complicated to work out corresponding values for $f(x)$ and then find the difference between them.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Are you allowed to use calculus?  What have you tried? Where are you stuck?  Please edit your question to include this information.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Yes, I am using calculus to find stationary points. I can find complicated values for x (in terms of t) for the max and min, but it seems too complicated to then find associated values for f(x) and then to find the difference between them. I keep looking for my error and not seeing it!

Comment: Showing us your work would make it easier for us to detect any errors you may have made.

Comment: $$f(x) = (3x^2 -4)(x-t+\frac1t)$$
$$f'(x) = (3x^2 -4)(1) + 6x(x - t + \frac1t)$$
stationary points when f'(x) = 0
$$0 = 9x^2 -6x(t-\frac1t) - 4$$
find values for x using quadratic formula gives:
$$x = \frac{(t-\frac1t)\pm\sqrt(t^2 + \frac1t^2)}{3}$$

I am not sure if this is right so far, but if it is ... it seems very complicated to work out corresponding values for f(x) and then find the difference between them. 

Can you help?

Comment: Small mistake in the discriminant, which is $36(t^2+2+1/t^2) = 6^2(t+1/t)^2$

Comment: Brilliant ... all sorted now. Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you know what to do next and just refuse to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you can factor the derivative as

$$ \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x} f = \tfrac{1}{t} ( 3x -2 t) ( 3 t x + 2) = 0 $$

which gives you the $x$ values for the extrema

$$ \begin{gathered} x = \frac{2 t}{3} & x = -\frac{2}{3 t} \end{gathered} $$

For the next part, you can do a variable substitution with $ u = t + \frac{1}{t}$ since the answer you are looking for is in terms of $u$.

$$ f = (x - \sqrt{ u^2-4}) ( 3 x^2 - 4) $$

and

$$ \begin{gathered} x = \frac{\sqrt{u^2-4}-u}{3} & x = \frac{\sqrt{u^2-4}+u}{3} \end{gathered} $$

At this point plug in the extrema $x$ into $f$ and simplify. Take the difference between the two results.